# Codimension of a closed subscheme - finite surjective morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a finite surjective morphism of smooth and irreducible projective varieities. Suppose $Z$ is a closed subscheme of $Y$. Then is the $codim_Y(Z)=codim_X(f^{-1}(Z))$?

Since $f$ is finite and surjective, then $dim{X}=dim{Y}$. Also $f^{-1}(Z)\rightarrow Z$ is a finite, surjective map, since it the base change of a finite morphism. Then $dim(f^{-1}(Z))=dim(Z)$. Thus the claim is true. Is this argument correct?

Comment: Yes this is true. Note that the fact that you work with projective varieties (i.e. of finite type over a field) is crucial, because you only showed equality of dimensions and not of co-dimensions. So you need the fact that co-dimension and dimension of a subscheme add up to the dimension of the ambient scheme. This is not true in general.

Comment: @MooS, can you tell me the statement about the additivity dimension and codimension in case of projective varieties?

Comment: This is for example Theorem 1.8A in the first chapter of Hartshorne.

Comment: @MooS, Thanks! I will accept it if you could make your comment an answer.